# clean URL using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, clean-urls

I'm trying to redirect the links on my domain.
What I'm trying to achieve is:
When the user clicks on a link to

`mydomain.com/index.php?dir=myfolder`

I want him to be redirected to exactly this URL but the browser bar is supposed to show this URL:

`mydomain.com/myfolder`

Since I don't have access to how the links are established (it's a php-site) I am trying to do this with just the .htaccess-file.

This is what I have:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} subdomain.mydomain.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)/style.css [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)/script.js [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)/logo.png
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.subdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?dir=$1 [L]
```

So when I enter `"mydomain.com/myfolder"` into the browser it works fine and the URL in the address-bar stays like this. But when I enter `"mydomain.com/index.php?dir=myfolder"` it works as well but the URL also stays the same (which is not what I want).
I assume that I need to somehow change the URL with the .htaccess-file and have it then (as I already have) rewritten to then php-scheme.
I did several approaches now but I have no idea how to do this.
I hope you understand my question and can help me!

Thank you!

```
EDIT:
```

The solution ( thanks to @anubhava):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+index\.php\?dir=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?dir=/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just append this rule at the end of your existing .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+index\.php\?dir=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
I put this code before the 

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?dir=/$1 [L]`


works perfect!

Answer (score 1):

I think you question is about making `/index.php?dir=example` redirect to `/example`. The below example issues a permanent redirection:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php\?dir=?$ /$1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

Comment: This is what I try to do, yes.
But this code (maybe I put it in at the wrong place) doesn't work either, it does not change the URL in the address bar...

Comment: This code will not work because RewriteRule cannot match query string, it is used to match just the URI part (without query string).

Answer (score 0):

To prettify URLs of the format `mydomain.com/index.php?dir=myfolder` as `mydomain.com/myfolder`, try the following rewrite rule in your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ /index.php?dir=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Problem remains: The URL in the browser's address bar stays `mydomain.com/index.php?dir=myfolder`