# htaccess remove index.php?page=

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I currently have urls that look like: `something.com/index.php?page=pagename` 
we would like to have it just be `something.com/pagename`
But still be able to access sub folders like `something.com/admin/`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [clean URL using .htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12976342/clean-url-using-htaccess)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Apache, which I presume you are, you need to use the ReWrite Engine:

If you don't have one already, create or add to the .htaccess file stored in the root directory you're rewriting. So you if you want something.com/index.php?* to rewrite, then use put it in the folder where something.com is stored.

There, you need something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /index.php?topic=$1 [QSA,L]
```

This regex takes the beginning of the input after "/", and uses that input as the variable $1.

Source: http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/

You then change all your links to point to "/pagename"

You may also have to turn on the RewriteEngine module by uncommenting it in your httpd.conf file by finding the line like:

```
#LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so
```

and deleting the leading `#`

More info: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: This doesn't work properly. With `index.php` effectively gone, I get the following server error:`Cannot serve directory /home/foobar/public_html/content/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.php,index.html,index.htm) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive`

Comment: @mig81 I'm not sure if this 6.5 year old answer is up to do with modern Apache, but at a glance from your error message it looks like there's something else wrong with your setup. I would suggest writing a new question.